# Is it possible to change the shortcut for the new search tabs feature in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

It's currently assigned to Ctrl + Shift + A but I would prefer a different shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because it's a newer feature, there's not a whole bunch of options for you, and Chrome doesn't really offer a proper native option, but here's what I was able to do:

**Download the extension [Quick Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb?hl=en).** This extension offers a tab searching feature like the one invoked via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>:

[image]

You are then able to assign *that* extension with it's own shortcut to open it, by going to `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` and locating the extension "Quick Tabs". You can then assign it a custom shortcut for that extension there, giving you the basic functionality you want! I've assigned mine to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>

[image]

I think this is the best solution for now, until Google adds a proper hotkey-changing option for their own functions.